# Trigger a workflow based on the status of a column

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, workflow-variable

Is it possible to trigger an approval flow based on the status of a column in a SharePoint List?

Eg. If column A = Value X ---> Trigger workflow.

If column X is any other value than X don`t trigger the flow.

Basically, I want to create a trigger button for the flow.

Thanks!

Comment: you can create a button to trigger flow using json formatting. but you have to click the button to trigger the workflow. Else you can create a workflow and pause until the status value becomes `Value X`. or you can create workflow which will start on item creation/updation. If value is not `Value X` then you can terminate it and its value is `Value X` you can perform your operations in workflow.

Comment: Hello Ganesh, thank you very much for your response. I have one question, how do I pause a flow? I tried searchig for the Pause function on SharePoint Online but can`t seem to find it

Comment: Then go for second approach, check [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Wait-for-field-change-in-Lists/td-p/135834) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

just like Ganesh said, it will be better to use an no Branch to end the flow and make the trigger to be when an item is created/modified. So whenever the item is modified/changed, the flow will be triggered and check the required column value.

Here is a sample flow for your reference
[image]